# How to use custom markers with leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, tilemill

I am pulling marker data from a shared CSV on google doc. I can get them mapped ok in leaflet. I want to use my own PNG markers. I also want to assign different markers by data category (if 'employees' field = <10 then use employee10.png )

Answer (score 0):

There's an example on the docs page for markers with custom icons: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'leaf-green.png',
    shadowUrl: 'leaf-shadow.png',

    iconSize:     [38, 95], // size of the icon
    shadowSize:   [50, 64], // size of the shadow
    iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
    popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});
```

Define all your icons, then use them when creating markers. For example,

```
var employeesLowIcon = L.icon({ ... });
var employeesHighIcon = L.icon({ ... });
var markerIcon = employees < 10 ? employeesLowIcon : employeesHighIcon;
L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: markerIcon }).addTo(map);
```